Power apss datatable
I've been learning a bit about MS power apps for a project recently and I seem to have hit a road block which I'm hoping someone could help me with.
I'm still self learning about power apps but I am unable to find anything that can guide in my task
Some information on my task at hand, I have an excel spreadsheet with multiple tables. Each table is assigned to an employee, the name of the table will be first_last name. This app I'm hoping to place on our SharePoint website, so I would like to extract their name from their log in to display their table.
I'm struggling to understand how to get this in a data table or an alternative is currently eluding me.
This excel file does have visual basic code as well.
I know how to do it manually, which I can do. But my hope is to have it automated, also the reason why I used vba in the excel workbook.

I've created a very simple xls spreadsheet with two worksheet, named after the employees (Person1 and Person2). You need to save this speadsheet somewhere where the PowerAutomat can find it (for example Sharepoint). Mainly, you need an action "Get worksheet". The action's output will contain the worksheet name (the spreadsheet's tab) name, which you can manage, for example put it into an array variable. See attached picture:

